# Data structure to choose for ordered items?

Tags: boundedvec, storagemap, vec

Can someone help me understand the difference b/w using a `Vec` (BoundedVec) instead of a `StorageMap` for storing ordered items? Basically inside a vector, the index would be an indicator of order whereas one may equivalently represent the same data as a `StorageMap<Identity, u32, Data>` where `u32` acts as the ordering. The reason for choosing `Identity` hasher for the key is simple, I just care about the keys acting as indices. I am planning on iterating through this data structure so as far as I can tell, the difference is just in syntax:

```rs
// Vec
vec.iter()
```

vs

```rs
// StorageMap
for i in 1..n {
 Storage::get(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance is the most important aspect here.

`Storage::get(i)` reads/decodes only the `i`th item from DB.

`Stgorage::get().iter().nth(i)` reads/decodes the entire storage item from DB and then indexes to `i`.

And the same theory applies to writing/encoding.